# How do I shorten this fragment of regex code?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following function in Java, which takes in a String comment and returns comment but with all trailing `#` characters and any `#` characters that have a space after them remove, and any sequence of multiple adjacent hashtags, such as `###`, replaced with a single `#` character. This is the code segment

```
private static String replaceHashTagsAndPunctuation(String comment) {
// Remove trailing '#' values
comment = comment.replaceAll("#*$", "");

// Replace instances of multiple '#' values with one '#'
comment = comment.replaceAll("#+", "#");


// Remove punctuation
comment = comment.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 #]", "");

// Remove all hashtags that have no word after them
comment = comment.replaceAll("# ", "");

return comment;
}
```

This is incredibly verbose and ugly. So my question is:
How can I rewrite this using better regex statements to remove all of these parts of the String in one or two lines?
Also, an explanation for why the regex code you suggested works would help me get a better understanding of how regular expressions work in Java.

Comment: I would argue that this is not ugly because it is verbose and clearly separated. Readability should generally be king in how you write code, unless it seriously hampers performance. Also, it's easy to add and remove different kinds of replacements in this form, whereas combining it into one regex may make adding/removing specific replacements rather difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clean up just once:

`comment = comment.replaceAll("#+", "#").replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 #]|# |#*$", "");`

Bar in regex means `OR`.

Comment: Thanks ayanami, your answer was the closest to what I was looking for. But also thanks to everyone for teaching me it's OK to tradeoff wordiness for readability. I have one more followup question though. Does the second replaceAll call here go through the String character by character, and for each character first checking if a [^a-zA-Z0-9 #] matches, and if not checks if a '# ' matches, and if not finally ends with checking if a "#*$" matches? Then, if any of these matches are made, it replaces the matched sequence with a "", and then continues checking every subsequent character similarly?

Comment: It's not strictly char by char (since `"# "` is two chars wide, and `"#*"` has an unknown width), but yeah, it looks for the first available match, replaces it, repeats until end-of-string. If you're thinking performance, then whatever is anticipated to be the most frequent match should come first. Also `#+` is better than `#*`, since the latter always matches (it's "zero or more", that's true for any given position in string).

Answer (score 1):

**Idea 1**

How would this do to replace two of your calls:

```
comment = comment.replaceAll("#+([ #])", $1);
```

Which works slightly different from the two you have by leaving the trailing space there:

```
comment = comment.replaceAll("#+", "#");
comment = comment.replaceAll("# ", "");
```

I don't know if the trailing space is important to remove because your words said "remove any # with a space after them" but didn't say to remove the space. However, the code does remove it.

**Idea 2**

It adds some complexity but you could take care of three of them with:

```
comment = comment.replaceAll("#+([ #]|$)", $1);
```

**Explaining**

The `$1` in the 2nd parameter means you replace the matched string with the whatever part of it matched the part inside the parentheses.

The `[ #]` means either a space or a number sign.

Together the `[# ]|$` means a space, a number sign or the end of the string.

Comment: Actually, this can result in a slower solution overall. It is better to work with fewer, but less complicated, regexes.

Comment: @fge You never know until you try both and time them. Even then it's hard to get past the JIT stuff and optimizations inherent in looping over do nothing code in a test program.

Answer (score 1):

The code has nothing wrong per se, but it may be factorized.

For instance:

```
// LinkedHashMap: insertion order matters!
private static final Map<Pattern, String> REPLACEMENTS
    = new LinkedHashMap<Pattern, String>();

static {
    Pattern pattern;
    String replacement;

    pattern = Pattern.compile("#*$");
    replacement = "";
    REPLACEMENTS.put(pattern, replacement);

    pattern = Pattern.compile("#+");
    replacement = "#";
    REPLACEMENTS.put(pattern, replacement);

    // etc
}
```

Then your code could be:

```
private static String replaceHashTagsAndPunctuation(final String comment)
{
    String ret = comment;

    for (final Map.Entry<Pattern, String> entry: REPLACEMENTS.entrySet())
        ret = entry.getKey().matcher(ret).replaceAll(entry.getValue());

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: The `compile()` call will prepare the regex ahead of time and is a good thing to do for code called many times. OP could do the same thing without using the cool idea of putting them all in a `Map` as well.

Comment: @LeeMeador I have some distant memory of `.replaceAll()` on `String` also caching `Pattern`s somewhat, so this may be not much of a gain... But extending the list of replacements, though, is easier this way ;)

Comment: The regex-related methods of the String class do not cache anything.  Neither do the methods of Pattern and Matcher.  The only class in the standard library that caches compiled regexes is `java.util.Scanner`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to begin with, I think your starting regexes are clear and understandable and solid, which are rare and valuable features in regular expressions, so if I saw this in code I was working on I would not change it.  Lee's one-liner:

```java
comment = comment.replaceAll("#+([ #]|$)", $1);
```

is compact and correct and clever, but hard to understand completely at first glance.  While I consider myself a wiz at regex, I still have to stop and think and unpack the 3 cases encoded in the regex to figure out what it is going to do.

If you want to pretty your code up without going to such extremes, I would recommend:

```java
// Replace instances of 1 or more consecutive '#' values with a single '#'
comment = comment.replaceAll("#{1,}", "#");  // 1

// Strip out '#' followed by space or at end of line
comment = comment.replaceAll("#( |$)", "");  // 2
```

1. Replaces 1 or more "#" with a single "#"
2. Deletes "#" followed by space or at the end of the line.  This deletes a single trailing space after a "#", too.  To preserve the space, change the replacement to "$1".